# How to implement Trigger on junction object to update field on contact

Tags: apex, trigger, junction-object

I have a junction object called `contact_role__c` between `contact` and a custom object called `property__c`. I need to update a field on `contact` object whenever a new `property__c` is created. This is what i have done so far. The trigger is not into the loop. Please tell my why that is happening and if this approach is correct or not

```
trigger countProperty on contact_role__c (after insert, after delete) {
list<contact_role__c> conList = new list<contact_role__c>();
if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete){ 
    conlist = trigger.new;
}

if(trigger.isDelete){
    conlist = trigger.old;
}

set<Id> conId = new set<Id>();
for(contact_role__c con : conList)
    conId.add(con.id);
}

for(contact con : [select id, (select id from contact_roles__r) from contact where id =: conId]){
    con.total_property__c = con.contact_roles__r.size();         
}
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MartinLezer I have updated the question

Comment: Shouldn't this be a trigger on the Property?

Comment: @MohitJoshi Is this a true junction object, with a master-detail relationship between contact_role__c and contact, rather than a lookup relationship? If so, have you already tried a roll-up field? It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but a roll-up would be easier to setup and maintain if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to writing triggers, please review this trailhead. It will help you get the syntax and basic functionality.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_beginner/modules/apex_triggers

Watch out for bulkification (no queries or updates in loops), so that your trigger won't break under data load conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the trigger should be on Property.. I eye balled this, but this may get you there..  You can do it without 2 for loops most likely, but I don't know your structure.

```
trigger countProperty on Property__c (after insert) 
{
    Set<ID> propertyIDs = new Set<ID>();

    for(Property__c p : Trigger.new)
    {
        propertyIDs.add(p.ID);
    }

    Map<ID, Contact> contactMap = new Map<ID, Contact>([SELECT ID, total_property__c,(SELECT ID from Contact_Roles__r) FROM Contact WHERE Property__c =: propertyIDs]);

    for(ID cid : contactMap.keySet())
    {
        Integer count = 0;
        for(Contact_Roles__c cr : contactMap.get(cid).Contact_Roles__r)
        {
            count++;
        }

        contactMap.get(cid).total_property__c = count;
    }

    update contactMap;
}
```